# Deploy once a specific branch with capistrano?

Tags: deployment, branch, capistrano

We have a very simple branching strategy:

- develop -> Development branch
- staging -> Staging Server Deploy Branch
- master -> Productio Branch

Our production deploy workflow is develop -> staging -> master. We always deploy first to staging, we test for some time, and then we deploy to production.

Right now we're working in a new feature that I would like to test. I don't want to put it in staging because, since is experimental, I would not like to lock a production deploy until the feature is finished.

Is there a way to say to capistrano the branch I want for one particular deploy, so I could put this experimental code in staging to test it?

OBS: The reason I need to put in staging is that this piece of code depends on a lot of external resources that are already configured in staging and would be difficult to replicate locally.

Comment: "We always deploy first to staging, we test for some time, and then we deploy to production"... so in your company "staging" really means "QA", right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how I do it.

At the top of my `config/deploy/staging.rb` file, I put this:

```
set :branch, ENV.fetch("CAPISTRANO_BRANCH", "staging")
```

This tells Capistrano that when I run `cap staging deploy`, use the `staging` branch by default, but allow that to be overridden by the `CAPISTRANO_BRANCH` environment variable.

So now if I want to deploy a custom branch to staging, it is as simple as this:

```
CAPISTRANO_BRANCH=my-feature cap staging deploy
```

Comment: Setting the 'CAPISTRANO_BRANCH variable like this in a mac terminal, will not make this variable accessible in the way described from within the rails console. I got it to work in a similar fashion using: export CAPSTRANO_BRANCH='my_feature'; you can remove the variable afterwards via: unset CAPISTRANO_BRANCH (tested on zsh)