# deployment not updating the local branch using capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, capistrano

I am trying to deploy the changes in the repo I made locally(merged master to local branch), but while the changes work on localhost, it does not update in the deployment, using bundle exec cap preproduction deploy.
I am new using capistrano.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I want to deploy the preproduction branch

Comment: did you run this : bundle exec git push origin preproduction

Comment: yes, and I get everyting up-to-date message. when I run the localhost, I can see the changes, but when I push to live, does not show.

Comment: try switch : bundle exec cap -S branch=preproduction deploy:setup

Comment: invalid option: -S

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38700400/deploy-once-a-specific-branch-with-capistrano

Comment: I tried it, but is does not sort the issue as the preproduction still have the older version live.